# how to save checkbox as a true or false in database

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

i am newbie in c# windows form programming. i am working on project that have too many check box name as checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3 ..... checkbox63.

how can i save, if user checked the check box then save value as a "true" in database and if user unchecked the check box then save value as a "false" in database.

i have 63 check boxes, how can i saved them in database.

i try this code. but i want to do it with loop. it is possible to do it, if is it then please share code with me

```
    string strCheckValue = "";

    if (checkbox1.Checked)

    {

      strCheckValue = "True";

    }

    if (checkbox2.Checked)

    {

      strCheckValue = "True";

    }
```

........ and so on.

please help...

Update::

i am using sql database. and every check box have a column in database, means that i have 63 check box and in sql database i have also 63 column. i just want that if user checked the check box then the value save "true" in database.

i know i making too much column. please suggest me right ways

Comment: Basically 0 or 1

Comment: `checkboxN.Checked` is already a bool. save that

Comment: You can easily loop over your controls if you have them all in a common container, such as a `Panel` (or really, whatever works..). As for the database aspect of it, you're missing a **lot** of details from you posted question. We don't even know what DB you're using, let alone if you've tried your own hand at inserting any data into it via C# code yet.

Comment: i have 63 check box, how can i save all check box value with one code. OR i write if condition for every check box

Comment: Also just to clarify, are you trying to save True in the database if *any* of your 63 checkboxes are checked? In your current code, you're sharing one variable `strCheckValue` for all of your checkboxes.

Comment: `how can i save all check box value with one code` does that mean all 63 map to one table?  Sounds like 63 different parameters.

Comment: It will involve more work up-front, but if you want to minimize user-written code, you could create a business object to hold all 63 booleans and then use a binding source component and map each text box to the various properties of your object.  The advantage of this is you can use a single event (bindingSource.CurrentChanged) to see if **ANY** of the values change and then save to the database.  There is no getting around the fact that you will need at least 63 parameters, unless you do dynamic SQL (which I discourage), so I'd take that as a given

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Don´t name your checkboxes like that. Name them after the real meaning of what they are suposed to do. It is much more simpler to know what "chkIsUserAdministrator" does than what "checkbox54" does.

Having said that, try to use a library such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). You will have to map the value of your checkbox to a corresponding datatype. For example if you use SQL, you can map the value as a BIT type.